# C# Constructor parameter should filled at runtime

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I have the following problem. I want to fill my constructor with *parameters* at runtime:

```
public Telegramme(int Sender, int Receiver, string Content, string length)
{
    ... 
}
```

So when I have a GUI with `TextBox`es, `senderTextBox` for example; `senderTextBox` is for the content of the `int Sender`; how can I give my constructor these information?

Comment: what is the relationship between your GUI and `Telegramme` ? is `Telegramme` your GUI class? Where will you call this constructor?

Comment: `var t = new Telegramme(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text),` and continue filling the `Receiver, Content, length` parameters

Comment: User should input information in GUI, this information should be send to the constructer, so every time i create a new object, the new object of telegramme should filled with the input automatically.

Comment: if one of the answers helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted as is [described in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `TryParse` given `string` values into corresponding `int` local variables:

```
  if (int.TryParse(senderTextBox.Text, out int sender) &&
      int.TryParse(receiverTextBox.Text, out int receiver)) {

    // Both senderTextBox.Text and receiverTextBox.Text contain valid values
    // which are parsed into integer sender and receiver variables

    Telegramme telegramme = new Telegramme(
      sender,
      receiver,
      contentTextBox.Text,        //TODO: put the right values here
      contentTextBox.Text.Length            
    );

    //TODO:Put relevant code here
  }
  else {
    // Invalid values in senderTextBox.Text or / and receiverTextBox.Text 

    //TODO:Put relevant code here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello invictuswarrior,

you should bind your text box content to a view model property.

Than use the view model property in your telegramm class.
Thus you have always access to the content of your textbox and you decouple the UI from your telegramm class.

Do it the same way for the other parameters.